# Pulseaudio says no cards available for configuration but there are at least TWO

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm running Debian 10 on my laptop.

I tried to install a driver for the realtek alc665 sound card. I  failed and as the result I don't have sound on my system.I can play songs but I can't hear anything though volume control is available and HIGH.

When I run `pavucontrol` audio mixer comes up and in the configuration tab I see:
`no cards available for configuration`
 In the output devices tab I see `dummy output`

I opened up a terminal and this is the output from `lspci -v`: (Only audio devices in this list)

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at f0a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Dell GF108 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at cdefc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

The output form `lshw -c multimedia` might also be usefull:

```
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED    
       description: Audio device
       product: GF108 High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:cdefc000-cdefffff
  *-usb:1
       description: Video
       product: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_2HDM
       vendor: CN07CN2C786640CA03F0A00
       physical id: 4
       bus info: usb@1:1.4
       version: 9.01
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=250mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
       description: Audio device
       product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
```

When I ran `alsa –version`  , I got this:

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
aplay: main:828: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

and finally this is the output from `aplay -l`:

```
aplay: device_list:272: no soundcards found...
```

It seems that drivers are currently available but not for pulseaudio. 
So how could I fix this?

Comment: Try "pulseaudio -k"

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I recently installed TiMidity++ (to get sound with Linthesia) and it was started automatically at boot time.

Maybe it will not fix your issue but to get sound through PulseAudio again, I had to stop the TiMidity++ service, for example if your Linux distribution is using Systemd, you can use the command `systemctl stop timidity` to stop the service and `systemctl disable timidity` to disable the service automatic startup.